# Sending email from gmail api not received but shown in sent folder

Tags: javascript, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I' m using gapi to send gmail. But if I send the mail to myself, it doesn't appear in my inbox. The most strange, it appears in the 'Sent' folder.
`

```
function sendMessage(email, callback) {
    // Web-safe base64 
    var base64EncodedEmail = btoa(email).replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/\+/g,'-');
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
        'userId': 'me',
        'message': {
            'raw': base64EncodedEmail
        }
    });
    request.execute(callback);
}

function send() {
    var var to = 'znlswd@gmail.com',
        subject = 'Hello World',
        content = 'send a Gmail.'

    var email = "From: 'me'\r\n"+
        "To:  "+ to +"\r\n"+
        "Subject: "+subject+"\r\n"+
        "\r\n"+
        content;
    sendMessage(email, function () {
        console.log(arguments);
    });
}
```

`
The information log in console is:

```
"[↵ {↵  "id": "gapiRpc",↵  "result": {↵   "id": "1471e09d88000bf7",↵   "threadId": "1471e09d88000bf7",↵   "labelIds": [↵    "SENT"↵   ]↵  }↵ }↵]↵"
```

And I can see this mail in the 'Sent' folder in Gmail, but I didn't get it in the inbox.
The original of this mail in the 'Sent' folder is as follow:

```
Received: from 823618323534-124pu7sujfj5olv94rkr0apqdppc6nti.apps.googleusercontent.com
named unknown
by gmailapi.google.com
with HTTPREST;
Wed, 9 Jul 2014 19:11:07 -0700
From: znlswd@gmail.com
To:  znlswd@gmail.com
Subject: Hello World
Date: Wed, 9 Jul 2014 19:11:07 -0700
Message-Id: <CADOxe9KLTdYfcb8OxWz+rFSM4tVKuZcVV8HJ4byv95+qPA=+dw@mail.gmail.com>

send a Gmail.
```

Anybody knows why? Thanks very much!

Edit:
I change the 'To:' in Mime message to another mailbox(not Gmail), and receive the mail correctly. Feeling More confused.

Edit:
I add a 'Cc': field, It is : znlswd@gmail.com(myself), 71848140@qq.com, swdpal2014@gmail.com, ezdiary@163.com . All the other guys(Gmail and other mailboxs) received the mail, but I still couldn't receive the mail from myself.

The original mail I received in ezdiary@163.com is as follow:

```
Received: from mail-qg0-f44.google.com (unknown [209.85.192.44])
by mx42 (Coremail) with SMTP id XMCowEAJvlfC_L1TjzExBg--.81S3;
Thu, 10 Jul 2014 10:39:03 +0800 (CST)
Received: by mail-qg0-f44.google.com with SMTP id j107so7126918qga.31
    for <ezdiary@163.com>; Wed, 09 Jul 2014 19:38:57 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
    h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to:cc:content-type;
    bh=zgoFEkSzE1bUNp54umXlfaDEDw5bLf2Ei0uFrgrVZic=;
    b=UHOLwuTsFL9yajR0nn/TskbhVKrIfzX4OAsNDno4S2QIvwx83H5dOe2WMyFbL6Plmk
     n4z2qzGjturoi1411+PGpgj8rt4Y57aDQpu7tEOMolMmFLJomtCSmagHIHhc0qwU+CRL
     rTjO2ztwZoj/ejnqwcmANzgzMMnSxxkcIf3OvXhLm+j+5yHQvPhmGWIapFWJaTN+9gb9
     Q47Qkqe5dBrsxOnGhgQnr1orbE5NcLIYumZTH1YfCMZvqIjUtmviUQUKpfhNQD5UtCX0
     0J2moKK98Q5Vek4Wti/WtnEqOgNTzHkIL1M90eeAJKelyPu4TQ7G9GJxr1FX+s4WhgrM
     xTFA==
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.224.137.9 with SMTP id u9mr78577439qat.24.1404959937414;
 Wed, 09 Jul 2014 19:38:57 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from 823618323534-124pu7sujfj5olv94rkr0apqdppc6nti.apps.googleusercontent.com
 named unknown by gmailapi.google.com with HTTPREST; Wed, 9 Jul 2014 19:38:56 -0700
From: znlswd@gmail.com
Date: Wed, 9 Jul 2014 19:38:56 -0700
Message-ID: <CADOxe9KF+VjMFw1bSkFd09RVsa7c7-pz9OguCFovOUemW4ZZbg@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Hello World
To: znlswd@gmail.com
Cc: 71848140@qq.com, swdpal2014@gmail.com, ezdiary@163.com
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
X-CM-TRANSID:XMCowEAJvlfC_L1TjzExBg--.81S3
Authentication-Results: mx42; spf=pass smtp.mail=znlswd@gmail.com; dki
m=pass header.i=@gmail.com
X-Coremail-Antispam: 1Uf129KBjDUn29KB7ZKAUJUUUUU529EdanIXcx71UUUUU7v73
VFW2AGmfu7bjvjm3AaLaJ3UbIYCTnIWIevJa73UjIFyTuYvjxUSeT5DUUUU

send a Gmail.
```

Edit: the original mail in swdpal2014@gmail.com is as follow:

```
Delivered-To: swdpal2014@gmail.com
Received: by 10.194.121.101 with SMTP id lj5csp1399131wjb;
    Wed, 9 Jul 2014 19:38:58 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <znlswd@gmail.com>
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of znlswd@gmail.com designates 10.224.137.9 as     permitted sender) client-ip=10.224.137.9
Authentication-Results: mr.google.com;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of znlswd@gmail.com designates 10.224.137.9 as             permitted sender) smtp.mail=znlswd@gmail.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@gmail.com
X-Received: from mr.google.com ([10.224.137.9])
    by 10.224.137.9 with SMTP id u9mr68151154qat.24.1404959937949 (num_hops = 1);
    Wed, 09 Jul 2014 19:38:57 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
    h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to:cc:content-type;
    bh=zgoFEkSzE1bUNp54umXlfaDEDw5bLf2Ei0uFrgrVZic=;
    b=UHOLwuTsFL9yajR0nn/TskbhVKrIfzX4OAsNDno4S2QIvwx83H5dOe2WMyFbL6Plmk
     n4z2qzGjturoi1411+PGpgj8rt4Y57aDQpu7tEOMolMmFLJomtCSmagHIHhc0qwU+CRL
     rTjO2ztwZoj/ejnqwcmANzgzMMnSxxkcIf3OvXhLm+j+5yHQvPhmGWIapFWJaTN+9gb9
     Q47Qkqe5dBrsxOnGhgQnr1orbE5NcLIYumZTH1YfCMZvqIjUtmviUQUKpfhNQD5UtCX0
     0J2moKK98Q5Vek4Wti/WtnEqOgNTzHkIL1M90eeAJKelyPu4TQ7G9GJxr1FX+s4WhgrM
     xTFA==
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.224.137.9 with SMTP id u9mr78577439qat.24.1404959937414;
 Wed, 09 Jul 2014 19:38:57 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from 823618323534-124pu7sujfj5olv94rkr0apqdppc6nti.apps.googleusercontent.com
 named unknown by gmailapi.google.com with HTTPREST; Wed, 9 Jul 2014 19:38:56 -0700
From: znlswd@gmail.com
Date: Wed, 9 Jul 2014 19:38:56 -0700
Message-ID: <CADOxe9KF+VjMFw1bSkFd09RVsa7c7-pz9OguCFovOUemW4ZZbg@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Hello World
To: znlswd@gmail.com
Cc: 71848140@qq.com, swdpal2014@gmail.com, ezdiary@163.com
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

send a Gmail.
```

Comment: Have you verified that it didn't end up in your spam folder? :)

Comment: um, yes! I check all folders but still can't find it :(

Comment: You received it when sending to a non-gmail destination? Does the received message look the same (including headers) as the one in your Sent folder?

Comment: @SMcCrohan I paste the mail headers received in <ezdiary@163.com>, could you find something? Thanks very much!

Comment: It can be sent to other gmail users, but not yourself? That's interesting. What happens when you send it as swdpal2014@gmail.com?

Comment: @SMcCrohan I have just tested it, the situation is the same,  swdpal2014@gmail.com couldn't receive email from itself while others could receive normally including znlswd@gmail.com :(

Comment: What if you use 'me' as the To: address? (As you did for From)

Comment: @SMcCrohan I tried, but Gmail sent me a mail telling me the mail didn't reach the destination. It seems 'me' can only be used in 'From' in the Gmail API. Thank you very much for your attention on my question! :)

Comment: Can you please provide me the link to the client library where I can access  gapi.client.gmail.users ? the one provided in google site doesn't have the gmail method. The one I used is <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer the question myself. First I tried using messages.insert. However, if I set the 'From' the same as the 'To'(my email address), the mail will still only be in the 'SENT' folder. the right way is using the message.modify api to add 'INBOX' and 'UNREAD' label to the mail sent.

```
gapi.client.request({
     path: "gmail/v1/users/me/messages/" + messageid + "/modify",
     method: "POST",
     body: "{\"addLabelIds\": [\"UNREAD\",\"INBOX\"]}",
     callback: function() {
         console.log("gmail sent to self");
         return console.log(arguments);
     }
})
```

The 'messageid' refer to the id return by the send api.

Comment: I wouldn't say using messages.modify to do this after the fact is "the right way" but agree that's what's necessary presently.

If you do just want to put a message in the authenticated user's own inbox then messages.insert does make sense, you can specify arbitrary labels.  If you are actually sending (e.g. it may go to any user, including this user) then messages.send is the right solution.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I am trying to send an email to a different gmail account. The mails appear in the Sent items of the first account. But I do not receive all of the mails in the second account. :(

Answer (score 1):

So to be clear, sending mail works as it sends correctly to others.  In the case of sending mail to yourself (why exactly are you doing this?  is this really needed as opposed to say just using messages.insert?) then it appears in only SENT but not also INBOX label.  You only get one copy of the mail, that's the same irregardless of API or using web UI.  The problem is that the web UI also puts that message in INBOX as well as SENT.  (As you can tell, sending to yourself is a bit of a special case due to things like dupe-detection based on the Message-Id header, etc.)

Comment: Thanks! What you said helps me a lot. At last I use the users/messages/modify api to add 'INBOX' and 'UNREAD' label to the mail in the 'SENT' folder. This perfectly solved my problem.

Comment: GmailGuy: It still seems like the messages.send API should do this for us. Now I have to ask users for "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify" auth scope just because they might want to send an email to themselves and have it show up in their inbox.

Comment: Yes, I agree messages.send(to=me) should do this--it's a bug...check back in a week or two.

Answer (score 0):

An untested idea: you can try adding an `X-Gmail-Labels: Inbox` header to the `messages.send` REST call in hopes that Gmail will add the label. I saw this header when doing a Google Takeout of some labels in GMail to mbox files.